# How to disable a specific validation rule during a transaction?

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

I have two models: Files and Courses. Files belongs to Course and has a CourseId field.

At some point I needed to use transactions to validate both of them before inserting them, however, one of my validation rules for the File model verifies if the informed CourseId exists (it's useful in other cases where I don't use transactions) and this rule is flagged during the transaction because there's no CouseId during it, as we can all expect.

```
models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    // if we want to insert a new course
    if (formData.courseId == 0) {
        return models.course.create({
            name: formData.courseName,
            fieldOfStudy: formData.fieldOfStudyId
        }, {transaction: t}).then(function(course) {
            return models.file.create({
                name: formData.name,
                universityId: formData.universityId,
                status: 1,
                type: formData.typeId,
                createdBy: userId,
                file_raw: files,
                courseId: course.id // here is the problem!
            }, {transaction: t});
        });
    // if we want to use a existing one                
    } else { 
        return models.file.create({
            name: formData.name,
            universityId: formData.universityId,
            courseId: formData.courseId,
            status: 1,
            type: formData.typeId,
            createdBy: userId,
            file_raw: files
        }, {transaction: t});
    }
})
```

This could be fixed if I could dinamically disable the validation rule for the CourseId field, but apparently this is not possible yet. Another approach would be virtual fields, but this one is not quite "elegant".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is not documented for the ".create() method", but there's a simple solution: `skip`.

As we can see [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/instance.js#L765-L778), the method .validate has a "skip" option. In order to fix the problem we just need to set skip to ["courseId"]:

```
return models.file.create({
    name: formData.name,
    universityId: formData.universityId,
    status: 1,
    type: formData.typeId,
    createdBy: userId,
    file_raw: files,
    courseId: course.id
}, {skip: ['courseId'], transaction: t});
```